# Why does XNA upgrade VS 2010 from v. 10 to v. 11?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, xna, xna-4.0

When you download Visual Studio Express 2010 it will install as version 10. If you have projects that are version 11 (still Visual Studio Express 2010) then they will not load. How do you upgrade from version 10 to 11?

I have tried to upgrade with the program itself, but it takes me to a defunct Microsoft link.

P.S. The link to the ISO of Visual Studio Express 2010 is dead: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express-iso. However where it links to is not: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9709969. Use the last link to download it.

Comment: Why was this closed? This problem can be reproduced and is not a typographical error. Please re-open.

I can reproduce this.

Head to this link to download this version of VS and open a project, and follow the exact steps he illustrated:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/hh442898.aspx#searchTerm=visual%20studio%202010&ProductFamilyId=0&Languages=en&Architectures=x86&ProductFamilyIds=370&FileExtensions=.iso&PageSize=10&PageIndex=0&FileId=0

Comment: @DaveVoyles, thanks for the download tip!

Comment: Closed as "a problem that can no longer be reproduced" with Microsoft software, while a Sr. Tech Evangelist at Microsoft is stating it can be reproduced, including a link to the solution. Much to learn... you still have.

Comment: @DaveVoyles, heads up you need an MSDN subscription (not free) to use the search/link you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Visual Studio Express 2010 is version 10 and installing XNA 4.0 upgrades it to version 11 (specifically the projects created will be version 11 and Visual Studio will remain version 10). It now loads my version 11 projects!

Comment: That VS 2010 build can also be found on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/hh442898.aspx#searchTerm=visual%20studio%202010&ProductFamilyId=0&Languages=en&Architectures=x86&ProductFamilyIds=370&FileExtensions=.iso&PageSize=10&PageIndex=0&FileId=0

Comment: Update that on a fresh Windows 10 install that installing XNA 4.0 as well as XNA 4.0 Refresh did not upgrade Visual Studio Express 2010 to version 11. It remains at version 10. BUT, it loads Visual Studio 11 projects (which version 10 does not load), so it still seems to update it somehow. If anyone can explain why the version does not update to 11, let me know!

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. Projects created in Visual Studio after XNA 4.0 is installed will be version 11, however Visual Studio itself remains version 10.

Comment: See, there was value in keeping this open.